# Se requiere tener instalado excel para usars OPENDATASOURCE?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

Buenos dias, en el siguiente enlace encontré la forma de importar datos desde un Excel a SQL Server:

https://www.excel-sql-server.com/excel-import-to-sql-server-using-distributed-queries.htm

Sin embargo, como la aplicación desde la cual voy a ejecutar dicho comando esta en PHP, quisiera saber si es necesario que en el servidor donde esta el código, se encuentre instalado Office, especificamente Excel.

Comment: No, para nada, es **SQL Server** quien se enargara de interpretar el archivo

Comment: Solo es necesario que instales en el servidor el driver en base a la versión de tu Excel.

Answer (score 1):

No es necesarío tener instalado MS Excel en el servidor.

Pero tendrás que instalar el driver `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 driver` (para versiones 2007-2010) o `Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0` (para versiones 97-2003) para poder realizar las importaciones.

Comment: Al usar `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` solo son para archivos **2007-2010**, en cambio `Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0` es para archivos **97-2003** :)

Comment: Añadida la versión a la respuesta. Gracias